# Outlook has not showing properly contact fields during create and update contact using MAPI API in MFC?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mapi

Before getting all properties shown all values in **screenshot**

[image]

I am first gets **all field value** of contact.

Then I created new contact in outlook and after all field value set on newly created contact.

shown in **image** new created contact.

[image: new]

**focus** on **yellow** mark properties. something missing and something wrong.

But i get all properties newly created contact **programmatically** it gets correct value.

I frustrated...

**I need help !!!!**

Answer (score 0):

You could try [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) to find out.

Comment: I install outlook spy but it ger error : your system ha not modified and please install outlook ... but i already installed outlook

Comment: Possible it is some issue with with OutlookSpy. I suggest you to try install Outlook and OutlookSpy on a clean machine, for example on virtual machine using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)